# How to Set the UIPickerView Initiated Row?

Tags: ios, settings, uipickerview, nsuserdefaults

I'm using `UIPickerView` in my app. I used some tutorials to do the settings and to take the selected data from the user, and it's working fine.

What I'm not clear about is how to tell the `UIPickerView`, when it's initiated with data (using `- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`), to point at a certain value.

To be more specific:

- I have a UIPickerView that holds an array of `NSStrings`
- Once the user selects a value I get it and keep it via `NSUserDefaults`
- When the user gets back to the `UIViewController` that holds the `UIPickerView`, I want to get the saved data from `NSUserDefaults` and have the `UIPickerView` point to the value that was saved there.

Where should I write the code that sets this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would write it on `ViewWillAppear:` (because this is when you want to set the data).

There you can read the value from you model (Core Data, `NSUSerDefaults`, Plist, etc.) and set it using:

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

This is a method of the [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectRow:inComponent:animated:).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for a while. Here was my solution:

In viewDidLoad

```
[_picker selectRow:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:"objectname"]intValue] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

This makes sure that you go to the row with that object in it. Pretty much the answer above with an example of how to specify the row of your exact NSUserDefault.

Answer (score 0):

This works great! Try it! The `rowNumberSelectedFirst` I used in my example is just a variable that holds the row number you wanted to get selected first when your `UIPickerView` is loaded.

For **swift 3** you can use this.

```
let rowNumberSelectedFirst: Int = 3
 pickerView.selectRow(rowNumberSelectedFirst, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

For **Objective-C** you can use this

```
int rowNumberSelectedFirst = 3; 
[picker selectRow:rowNumberSelectedFirst inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```